# Non type-variable argument in the constraint error while using foldl with ++

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use fold with ++. It should work as I check the type of it:

```
> :t foldl (++)
foldl (++) :: Foldable t => [a] -> t [a] -> [a]
```

When I try to use it like this

```
> foldl (++) [1] [1,2,3]
```

I get an error like:

> Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
>       (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your fold evaluates to `((([1] ++ 1) ++ 2) ++ 3)` which is ill typed, since `++` needs two lists. GHC tries to make this work by converting each of `1,2,3` to a list, by requiring `Num [a]`, which fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the type of your `foldl (++)` function, the `t` is important here:

```
foldl (++) :: Foldable t => [a] -> t [a] -> [a]
```

If you pass `[1] :: Num n => [n]` as a first argument, that is not a problem, since then your `[1]` as type `[a]`, and hence `a ~ n`.

The second argument however *is* a problem. You here pass a list `[1,2,3] :: Num m => [m]`, with a type `Num m => [m]`, or more canonical `Num m => [] m`. The only possible way to let this match with `t [a]`, is to set `t ~ []` (`t` is the list *type* constructor), and then `[a]` should match with `m`, but Haskell does not know a `Num` type `m` that is a list `[a]`, hence it fails.

You can call this with for example:

```
Prelude> foldl (++) [1] [[2], [3,4]]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Since Haskell here will generate an expression that looks like:

```
(([1] ++ [2]) ++ [3]) ++ [4]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

We can also pass other `Foldable` types, like a `Maybe` for example:

```
Prelude> foldl (++) [1] (Just [2])
[1,2]
Prelude> foldl (++) [1] Nothing
[1]
```

In that case the second parameter should have type `Maybe [Int]`.

Comment: so in this cas t [a] is something like [[a]] ? so this type without typeclasses would be [a] -> [[a]] -> [a] right?

Comment: @heisenberg7584: indeed, since `[[b]]` in its canocnical form is `[] ([] b)`. So then it specifies `t ~ []`, and hence it sees `[] b ~ [] a`, and thus `b ~ a`.